Adapt context to log level in structlog
A common need when logging events is to provide more or less information depending on the log level. Consider the example below where some noisy payload should be included in the logs only if the log level is DEBUG or below. I found 3 possible approach so far:
import random
import logging
import structlog

log_level = logging.INFO
wrapper_class = structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger(log_level)
structlog.configure(wrapper_class=wrapper_class)
logger = structlog.get_logger()

noisy = random.randbytes(1024)

# Approach 1
logger.info("Approach 1")
logger.debug("Approach 1", noisy=noisy)

# Approach 2
if log_level <= logging.DEBUG:
    logger.debug("Approach 2", noisy=noisy)
else:
    logger.info("Approach 2")

# Approach 3
log = logger.bind(noisy=noisy) if log_level <= logging.DEBUG else logger.bind()
log.info("Approach 3")

All three approaches work correctly, especially with the INFO level:
2024-05-30 12:41:51 [info     ] Approach 1                    
2024-05-30 12:41:51 [info     ] Approach 2                    
2024-05-30 12:41:51 [info     ] Approach 3 

With the DEBUG level however, approach 1 would show two logs for the same event, which is OK but not great (as it can easily be mistaken for two different events when browsing the logs). Approach 2 does not have this problem, although having an INFO log disappear when switching to DEBUG is a bit confusing. My favorite so far is approach 3 which simply adds the noisy payload to the existing INFO log when the log level is DEBUG.
How is this issue typically addressed in real-world code bases? Is there some good practice about that? Am I missing a better approach or a dedicated functionality in structlog?

Something that could help you achieve that in a pretty clean way is the processors of structlog - https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/processors.html
Add a processor which checks whether the log level is debug and if yes, then it leaves the noisy parameter there, else it removes it from the event_dict.
I left below a sample implementation. Note that because a string based logger is used, our processors chain needs to output a string, so we add our custom processor which removes noisy if not debug then add another processor, the LogFmtRenderer one, which takes the event dict and transforms it into a string so it can be fed to the string based logger. See https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/processors.html#adapting-and-rendering for more details. Here are some processors which you can use out of the box from the struclog library https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/api.html#module-structlog.processors so you can customize the processor chain however you wish):
import random
import logging
import structlog

log_level = logging.INFO

def filter_out_noisy_if_debug(logger, log_method, event_dict):
    if log_level > logging.DEBUG and event_dict.get('noisy') is not None:
        del event_dict['noisy']

    return event_dict

wrapper_class = structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger(log_level)
structlog.configure(wrapper_class=wrapper_class, processors=[filter_out_noisy_if_debug, structlog.processors.LogfmtRenderer()])

logger = structlog.get_logger()

noisy = random.randbytes(1024)

logger.info("Info log with noisy", noisy=noisy)
logger.debug("Debug log with noisy", noisy=noisy)

Note that if you set the log level to INFO then only the first log without noisy will get printed. If you set the log level to debug then both will be printed and both with noisy.

Hmm interesting. That means there could be an informal policy like: any key starting with debug_ is filtered out if the level is debug. Sounds pretty good.
